# How to make elements such as text appear on top of stacked backgrounds?

Tags: html, dom, sass, gradient

I have a website with body containing fix background image and a div class containing transparent radial-gradient layer. How do I make the elements within the class to not be transparent and appear on top of the background gradient and background image?

CSS:

```
$body-color1: #f2009f;
$body-color2: #218bdb;

// Solution 1. However, unable too get content on top of gradient and backgourn image
html { min-height:100%; } /* to get the gradient to stetch to the bottom of the view port */
body {

  background: $body-color2;
  background: url('http://i.huffpost.com/gen/964776/thumbs/o-CATS-KILL-BILLIONS-facebook.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  // background-size: cover;

}

.bg-img {
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, $body-color1 0%, $body-color2 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0 $body-color1), color-stop(100%,$body-color2)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, $body-color1 0%,$body-color2 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, $body-color1 0%,$body-color2 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, $body-color1 0%,$body-color2 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, $body-color1 0%,$body-color2 100%); /* W3C */
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bg-img">Insert large body of text here or elements.</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPeqMJ

Comment: _“How do I make the elements within the class to not be transparent ”_ – by not using `opacity` – opacity works on an element including all of its content.

Comment: If I do that, I will lose the transparent gradient on top of the image. Image will get covered. Is there a way I can still have transparent gradient effect on top of the image while having opaque elements?

Comment: Gradients should work with `rgba` colors as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your body colors to:

```
$body-color1: rgba(242, 0, 159, 0.5);
$body-color2: rgba(33, 139, 219, 0.5);
```

and remove `opacity` from `.bg-img`

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaGjzW)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, Jon P! This is the answer that I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

for putthe element on the top, you can use the `z-index` property. Be sure that the value is large enough to preventother element to come at top

```
z-index: 99999;
```

Comment: I tried adding an inner class to bg-img with a different z-index. That didn't work either.